# Remove files after reboot

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there exist such way for deinstallation? If some file busy by some process, the deinstallation can't remove this file, and this file remains after removal. May I mark this file for remove after reboot by wix/msi?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mark a directory to be deleted after reboot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773374/how-do-i-mark-a-directory-to-be-deleted-after-reboot)

Comment: If a file is installed by Windows Installer, Windows Installer will remove it when it is no longer needed. You don't need to do anything.

Comment: Yan Sklyarenko, thanks, this is really what I was looking for.                                                                  Tom Blodget, Windows Installer won't remove folder, if folder opened in FAR, or some 0ther process uses this folder.